# How to skip the authorization page when changing accounts in Google calendar APIs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, calendar, google-api

We have a team doing a application where Google calendar APIs are used in this project. Since the application is meant to face multiple users, and Google requires a new authorization when we change to an another user. We think this makes the program not really practical, to make it more user friendly, we want to skip this step, is there any way we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are all the users on a single Google domain? If so, you could use [Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount). Once you have the service account credential, you can impersonate any user in the domain to show their calendars without needing further authorization.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Not sure what do you mean by Google domain. We are using gmail accounts to specify the users, when we switch users, we change it to their respective gamil account. I believe we need to rewrite the code if we change it to Service Accounts, am I right?

Comment: If the users are not on the same domain (such as is the case when a company has a company-wide set of google accounts), and are instead just a list of unrelated Gmail accounts, you will need to store credentials for each user. [This](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) and [this](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) may be helpful.